# ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'userstat'

Tags: mysql, variables, ssh, command-line, putty

I tried to change the status of userstat variable by going to mysql on server by ssh.

**Here are my steps:**

1. Open PuTTY
2. Connect by SSH

**command lines:**

3. mysql
4. SET GLOBAL userstat=on;

**Response:** ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'userstat'

After that, I run this command to see all variables: **SHOW VARIABLES;**

Answer (score 0):

As reported, there is no variable named USERSTAT.
You may be confusing VARIABLES with STATUS after reviewing the content of your question.
Both are always ON in MySQL.
Then you can
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES  or  SHOW SESSION VARIABLES  that would include any 'overrides' for this 'SESSION'.
Status has available  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS  or  SHOW SESSION STATUS  that will report NUMBER of times various events have been counted.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS reports counts since startup.
SHOW SESSION STATUS reports counts of this SESSION.
Caution, for very ACTIVE systems, counts reported by innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests ROLLOVER above ~ 4,200,000,000 and the only reliable count is recorded in information_schema.innodb_metrics row with buffer_pool_read_requests.   There may be other counters from STATUS with ROLLOVER problems depending on your version of MySQL.  This was true in 5.6.17 when running 64 bit version.

Comment: Only on 32-bit compiles does SHOW rollover.  SHOW and I_S are different windows into the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The `VARIABLE` `userstat_running` existed in Percona 5.1.

It was renamed to `userstat` in Percona 5.5.10 and MariaDB.

MySQL does not have either.